# how to separate header footer and sidebar in a html template with jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, html-templates

I have a template which has a header, footer, and sidebar; I want to separate them into separate files and include them in the main template. previously I was using PHP, and it was very easy to do this by `include()` or `required()` function, but since I am using node.js instead of PHP I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
$( "#header" ).load( "header.html" );
$( "#sidebar" ).load( "sidebar.html" );
$( "#footer" ).load( "footer.html" );

});
</script>
```

You can use jquery for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess doing something like

```
<% include ../partials/head %>
```

in your view should work just fine. You can also have a look [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can use W3schools library to achieve this easily.

[More info here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

add this script in your HTML

```
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
```

Call w3.includeHTML() to include the HTML:

```
<script>
w3.includeHTML();
</script>
```

full example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
w3.includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```